# BlockNumber stuck on 0 while a private network node is looking for peers

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, mining, balances, hashrate

I'm extremely new to Blockchain and mining, and I've followed this [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0) to create my first private blockchain. I am stuck when it comes to mining and I'm afraid I'm quite lost.
Afte I've started the miner with `miner.start()`, the geth console keeps generating the DAG in a loop-but eventually geneates it , and keeps looking for a peer, like this:

[image: peer looking]

I've googled a bit and figured the values of Blocknumber and hashrate are key to knowing what's happening , my blockNumber has been stuck on 0 while hashrate changed after 2 minutes of mining:

[image: Output of the two values]

Can anyone please help me understand what's going on and how can I fix this?